# @MessageDriven bean not receiving messages

Tags: java, singleton, ejb, jms, message-driven-bean

I made some changes per suggestions from another question to turn my class into a `@Singleton` rather than `@Stateless`, however I'm no longer receiving messages in my `@MessageDriven` Bean as I was before.  Suggestions? Note that the topic is correctly defined in `jbossmq-destinations-service.xml`

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton(mappedName="MySingletonClass")
public class MySingletonClass implements SomeInterface
{
   private Timer timer = null;

   @javax.annotation.Resource
   TimerService timerService;


   /**
    * Creates the timer.
    */
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void resetTimer()
   {
      if (timer != null)
      {
         timer.cancel();
      }
      timer = timerService.createTimer(30000, "Note");
   }

   @Override
   public void readResponseMsg(Document responseXml)
   {
      resetTimer();
      //Do stuff
   }

   @Override
   @Timeout
   public void timeout() throws RemoteException
   {
       //do stuff
   }
}
```

and the MDB:

```
@javax.ejb.MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/MyTopic", activationConfig = {
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "MyTopic"),
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messagingType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.MessageListener"),
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
@ResourceAdapter("activemq.rar")
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener
{
   private static final Logger ourLogger = Logger.getLogger(MyMDB.class);

   @javax.ejb.EJB(mappedName="MySingletonClass") private MySingletonClassInterface reader;

   /**
    * @param message
    */
   public void onMessage(Message message)
   {
      TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Received Message Text: " + textMessage.getText());
         reader.readResponseMsg(loadXMLFromString(textMessage.getText()));
      }
      catch (JMSException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException e)
      {
         ourLogger.error("Exception handling Schedule Results Message", e);
      }
   }
}
```

This is the interface:

```
@javax.ejb.Local
public interface SomeInterface
{
   public void readResponseMsg(Document responseXml);


   public void timeout() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**UPDATE** I've been fiddling with some things and am now seeing some exceptions that at least indicate something is happening.  I've updated the code above with my changes.  This is my exception:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MySingletonClass not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771) [:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779) [:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785) [:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:396) [:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:399) [:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:728) [:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688) [:5.0.5.Final]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.resolveLink(NamingContext.java:1350) [:5.0.5.Final]
    ... 61 more
```

Also, further up in the JBoss 6 startup log, I am also seeing this:

```
 [BeanInstantiatorDeployerBase] Installed org.jboss.ejb3.instantiator.impl.Ejb31SpecBeanInstantiator@fbda95 into MC at org.jboss.ejb.bean.instantiator/mmpl/server/MySingletonClass
```

then a little further down the log:

```
DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss-switchboard:appName=mmpl,module=server,name=MyMDB" is missing the following dependencies:
   Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=mmpl.ear,jar=server.jar,name=MySingletonClass,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.j2ee:ear=mmpl.ear,jar=server.jar,name=MySingletonClass,service=EJB3',whenRequired=MapControllerStateModel$ControllerStateWrapper@7ba014{Installed},dependentState=MapControllerStateModel$ControllerStateWrapper@7ba014{Installed} **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=mmpl.ear,jar=server.jar,name=MySingletonClass,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=mmpl.ear,jar=server.jar,name=MySingletonClass,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.j2ee:ear=mmpl.ear,jar=server.jar,name=MySingletonClass,service=EJB3' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=mmpl.ear,jar=server.jar,name=MySingletonClass,service=EJB3" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.j2ee:ear=mmpl.ear,jar=server.jar,name=MySingletonClass,service=EJB3',whenRequired=MapControllerStateModel$ControllerStateWrapper@7ba014{Installed},dependentState=MapControllerStateModel$ControllerStateWrapper@7ba014{Installed} **, ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.j2ee:ear=mmpl.ear,jar=server.jar,name=MySingletonClass,service=EJB3' **
```

Comment: It worked before, right? Does it work if you comment the usage of 'reader' bean (or the bean declaration itself)?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki Yes, messages are received if I comment out the `@EJB` line and its usage.  Do I need to declare my singletons in an XML somewhere or something?

Comment: No you don't need to declare them in XML. So there are no errors, even the first message is not arriving and no errors during deployment? One thing more - your Singleton EJB is implementing an interface. Do you have any annotations in this interface? Is it local business i-face (by default) or something else? In your MDB you're accessing Singleton using its actual class type instead of this interface, so you're trying to use no-interface view of the EJB. Do you declare it so (`@LocalBean`)? Can you try using its business interface instead?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki it only implements the `interface` to enforce some conventions between this and future, similar classes.  There are no annotations on the `interface`.

Comment: @PiotrNowicki also, if I use the `interface` in my MDB, how would it know which implementation of that `interface` to populate? Eventually there will be several

Comment: @PiotrNowicki Added the interface

Comment: If there are no annotations on the interface and your Singleton EJB is implementing it then by default it is a local business interface. If you don't have `@LocalBean` on the EJB than the local business interface is the only one that your EJB is exposing. I'm not sure why it even works in your case - I think app server should throw some exception because you're trying to use no-interface view (`@EJB` on the class itself - not the interface) but you don't declare your EJB is exposing this view.

Comment: If you have more than one implementation of a single interface you need to tell container what implementation to use (e.g. using `@EJB(beanName attribute). Are you sure it is a `@Singleton` annotation from EJB - not from CDI package?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki `@Singleton` annotation from EJB - not from CDI package?` Yes, `javax.ejb.Singleton`.  I don't understand your other comment - could you create an answer with a demonstration of what you mean?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki I added some additional information and edited the annotations in the code to reflect changes as I've poked around at this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37683/discussion-between-piotr-nowicki-and-stormehawke)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the ejb singleton idea and using the following, which works perfectly:

```
public class MySingletonClass implements SomeInterface
{
   private ScheduledFuture<?> handle;
   private static ScheduledExecutorService executor;
   private static SomeInterface instance;

   public void readResponseMsg(Document responseXml)
   {
       resetTimer();
       //do stuff
   }

   /**
    * Creates the timer.
    */
   private void resetTimer()
   {
      if (handle != null)
      {
         handle.cancel(false);
      }
      handle = executor.schedule(this, 30l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }


   /**
    * Initialize the static variables. Should only be called once per server
    * restart
    */
   private static void init()
   {
      try
      {
         executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
         inited = true;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         ourLogger.error("Exception initializing ScheduleResultReader", e);
      }
   }

   public static SomeInterface getInstance()
   {
      if (instance == null)
      {
         instance = new MySingletonClass();
      }

      return instance;
   }

}
```